# ExtJS - BoxSelect close icon

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I use 4.2.1 and the BoxSelect extension from [BoxSelect](http://kveeiv.github.io/extjs-boxselect/examples/boxselect.html)

The examples there show a close icon in the tags:

[image]

In 4.2.1 I have this example code:

```
        {
            name: 'tags',
            itemId: 'tags',
            xtype: 'boxselect',
            fieldLabel: "${cn.message(code: 'tags')}",
            forceSelection: false,
            createNewOnEnter: true,
            createNewOnBlur: true,
            store: 'States',
            queryMode: 'local',
            valueField: 'abbr',
            displayField: 'name',
            filterPickList: true, 
            pinList: false,
            growMax: 120,
            typeAhead: true,
        }
```

This looks like this:

[image]

Is it because of version 4.2.1 that the close icon is not showing?
Or is there some setting I'm missing?

I tried classic, gray and neptune theme.

---

**SOLVED**

Solution given at [missing close icon](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134751-Ext.ux.form.field.BoxSelect-Intuitive-Multi-Select-ComboBox/page18) is working for me.
Thanks @DoubleDouble for pointing out the page.

Adding this to BoxSelect.css solves it:

```
.x-boxselect-item-close {
    width       : 11px;
    height      : 11px;
    background-image: url(http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.2.0-gpl/resources/ext-theme-classic/images/tab/tab-default-close.gif);
    filter      : progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60);
    opacity     : 0.6;
    top     : 2px;
    right       : 2px;
}
.x-boxselect-list {
    margin:0px;
}
```

Looks like this now:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boxselect was updated for ExtJS 4.1

Take a look at the Sencha forum post, I believe farther in (maybe start from the back) people post some other code to modify it to work better in 4.2

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134751-Ext.ux.form.field.BoxSelect-Intuitive-Multi-Select-ComboBox

That being said, even with those changes I could not get BoxSelect to work the way I wanted to for my own project. Hope you have better luck than I did!

**Edit**

Page 18 seems to have your particular issue

Comment: Thanks! This fix is working for me. I updated the question with the code that solves this. Cheers, Guus

Comment: What issues did you have with this @DoubleDouble ?

Comment: @code4jhon I don't recall exactly, as it was nearly a year ago, but I think it was flakiness in how it handled typed separators (rather than clicking) and various other "small" weirdness. Since I was trying to match the behavior of another system, it ultimately was more acceptable to create my own with less overall functionality than it was to try and puzzle out all the little issues I was having.